# AngularJS Directive for select component

Tags: angularjs, html-select, directive, ng-options

I'm trying to create an AngularJS directive for a component that I'll be using multiple times in different places over my System.

Here's a simple example of where I'm stuck right now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">

        <div stk-customer></div>

        <div>
            <select-pais id="selectPais1" lista="listaPais" opcao="participante.idPais"/>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div>
            <select-pais id='selectPais2' lista='listaPais' opcao="participante.idNacionalidade"/>
        </div>

        <br />
        <div>
            <select-sim-nao id='selectSimNao' lista='listaSimNao' opcao='participante.temDinheiro' />
        </div>

    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            var vm = $scope;

            vm.participante = {
                'idPais' : '04',
                'idNacionalidade': '02',
                'temDinheiro': 'Não'
            },

            vm.listaPais = [
                {'id' : '01', 'pais' : 'Argentina'},
                {'id' : '02', 'pais' : 'Uruguai'},
                {'id' : '03', 'pais' : 'Paraguai'},
                {'id' : '04', 'pais' : 'Brasil'},
                {'id' : '05', 'pais' : 'Estados Unidos'},
                {'id' : '06', 'pais' : 'Canadá'}
            ],

            vm.listaSimNao = [
                'Sim',
                'Não'
            ]

        }]);

        app.directive('selectPais', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    listaPais: '=lista',
                    opcao: '='
                },
                template: '<select ng-options="item.pais for item in listaPais track by item.id" ng-model="opcao" required="required">' +
                        '<option value=""></option>' +
                    '</select>' + 
                    '<div>{{opcao}}</div>'
            }
        });

        app.directive('selectSimNao', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    listaSimNao: '=lista',
                    opcao: '='
                },
                template: '<select ng-options="item as item for item in listaSimNao" ng-model="opcao" required="required">' +
                        '<option value=""></option>' +
                    '</select>' +
                    '<div>{{opcao}}</div>'
            }
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

I need to be able to bind the object participante's different ids to my directive "select-pais" and make it select the right Country, but have no idea how to make it work.

I'm new to AngularJs and a lot of things are strange to me.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Why are you starting with AngularJS? Do Angular 2 (https://angular.io) or my favourite version of Angular 2, the AngularDart (https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/).

AngularJS is a bit outdated now.

Comment: @HoBi I'll do Angular 2, but for now the project I'm in uses AngularJs and I can't switch to the newer version. But thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an object because you are selecting by id, so you must have {id: 'idFromParticipante'}

As described in Angularjs API:

> Another solution is to use a track by clause, because then ngOptions will track the identity of the item not by reference, but by the result of the track by expression. For example, if your collection items have an id property, you would track by item.id.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#complex-models-objects-or-collections-

Here is an example:

```js
 var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            var vm = $scope;

            vm.participante = {
                'idPais' : '04',
                'idNacionalidade': '02',
                'temDinheiro': 'Não'
            },

            vm.listaPais = [
                {'id' : '01', 'pais' : 'Argentina'},
                {'id' : '02', 'pais' : 'Uruguai'},
                {'id' : '03', 'pais' : 'Paraguai'},
                {'id' : '04', 'pais' : 'Brasil'},
                {'id' : '05', 'pais' : 'Estados Unidos'},
                {'id' : '06', 'pais' : 'Canadá'}
            ],

            vm.listaSimNao = [
                'Sim',
                'Não'
            ]

        }]);

        app.directive('selectPais', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    listaPais: '=lista',
                    opcao: '='
                },
                controller: function($scope){
                    $scope.selecionado = {id: $scope.opcao}
                },
                template: '<select ng-options="item.pais for item in listaPais track by item.id" ng-model="selecionado" required="required">' +
                        '<option value=""></option>' +
                    '</select>' + 
                    '<div>{{opcao}}</div>'
            }
        });

        app.directive('selectSimNao', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    listaSimNao: '=lista',
                    opcao: '='
                },
                template: '<select ng-options="item as item for item in listaSimNao" ng-model="opcao" required="required">' +
                        '<option value=""></option>' +
                    '</select>' +
                    '<div>{{opcao}}</div>'
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">

        <div stk-customer></div>

        <div>
            <select-pais id="selectPais1" lista="listaPais" opcao="participante.idPais"/>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div>
            <select-pais id='selectPais2' lista='listaPais' opcao="participante.idNacionalidade"/>
        </div>

        <br />
        <div>
            <select-sim-nao id='selectSimNao' lista='listaSimNao' opcao='participante.temDinheiro' />
        </div>

    </body>
```

Codepen link:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxmKQp?editors=1010